# Can a point charge inside spherical shell conductor with non negligible thickness experience forces from other charges outside the conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

The title says all about the subject matter. Can a point charge stationed inside a spherical shell with non negligible thickness experience forces from other charges outside the conductor?

Answer (score 0):

A conducting spherical shell around a point charge forms a [Faraday Cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage). This system negates all electrostatic fields around it in a phenomenon known as electrostatic shielding. The point charge is hence isolated from all other electric fields outside the shell. This is also why phones do not work inside elevators.